# Unable to create Twitter application

Tags: twitter

I need to create a Twitter application to access the public API and collect data for my Master thesis. But I'm unable to do so due to the restriction about having to verify the account by entering my phone number.
my country isn't even listed! how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Curious, which country are you from?

Comment: Syria. I accepted the fact that I could never pay for twitter's enterprise API for my research, but the fact that I can't even access the free API that should be available to everyone is just depressing